# CakePHP - Model Associations/ binding

Tags: cakephp, model, model-binding, model-associations

I would like to bind models, mostly because the datasources change from one model to the other. Let's say I have the following query :

```
SELECT ext.col1, ext.col2, ext.col3, COUNT(*) Link Count
FROM `external.`Media` ext 
INNER JOIN `internal`.`links` l ON ext.someId = links.id
INNER JOIN `internal`.tags t ON l.tag_id = t.tag_id
WHERE t.parent_tag_id = 1098
AND t.metadata = 'someValue'
GROUP BY ext.col1, ext.col2, ext.col3
```

---

So I have 3 models from which data is coming from. Currently I have the following  in the  `Media` model..

```
public $belongsTo = array(
            'Links' => array(
                'className' => 'Links',
                'foreignKey' => 'someId',
            ),
            'Tag' => array(
                'className' => 'Tag'
            )
        );
```

---

Then in the other models :

**Tag Model**

```
public $useTable = "tags";
public $name = 'Tag';

public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'TagLink' => array(
        'className' => 'TagLink',
        'foreign_key' => 'tag_id',
        'conditions' => array(
            'Tag.parent_tag_id' => 1098
        )
    )
);
```

**Link Model**

```
public $useTable = "tag_links";
    public $name = 'TagLink';

    public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
        'Tag' => array(
            'className' => 'Tag',
            'foreign_key' => 'tag_id'
        )
    );
```

Then back in the `Media` model , I use the find expecting to have the model binding set up :

```
return $this->find("all", array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'Tag.metadata' => $username
    )
));
```

This generates an error :

`Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Tag.metadata' in 'where clause'`

I am assuming that this is happening because the table is not found

**[SQL Generated]**

```
    SELECT `Media`.`media_id`, `Media`.`mediatype`, `Media`.`created`, `Media`.`active_flag`, 
`Media`.`mediafile`, `Media`.`fallbackfile`, `Media`.`setupId`, `Media`.`externalId`, 
`Media`.`width`, `Media`.`height`, `Media`.`brands`, `Media`.`languages`, `Media`.`products`, 
`Media`.`projects`, `Media`.`affiliates`, `Media`.`description`, `Media`.`linking_code` FROM 
`external`.`ext_media_gallery` AS `Media` WHERE `Tag`.`metadata` = 'testuser' AND 
`MediaGallery`.`active_flag` = 'active' AND ((FIND_IN_SET('testuser', `Media`.`affiliates`)) OR 
(`Media`.`affiliates` = ''))
```

This basically shows that the binding is incorrect/not happening

Basically I want to replace the following to avoid using joins on the fly since these would need to apply for every query.. hence the model binding..

This works for me, but I want to convert it to do it using model binding :

```
return $this->find("all", array(
                "joins" => array(
                    array(
                        "table" => "internal.links",
                        "alias" => "Link",
                        "type" => "INNER",
                        "conditions" => array(
                            "Link.id = Media.someId"
                        )
                    ),
                    array(
                        "table" => "internal.tags",
                        "alias" => "Tag",
                        "type" => "INNER",
                        "conditions" => array(
                            "Tag.tag_id = Link.tag_id",
                            "Tag.parent_tag_id = 3214",
                            "Tag.metadata" => $username
                        )
                    ),
                )
            ));
```

Comment: What is the generated SQL statement?

Comment: @AgRizzo I updated the question to include sql statment

Comment: Maybe you can use the beforeFind method to add those JOINs automatically.

Comment: @AgRizzo Definitely I can do so.. and would help in not having to set the joins for every query.. However, I hoped to do this with model binding as I think this is a very practical example where model binding should be used..

Comment: When you say "model binding", are you referring to the model's associations? In Cakephp 2.x, model associations do not create the JOIN when the tables are located in different databases.

Comment: @AgRizzo Yes I am referring to association.. Where is it specified in cakePHP doc that a join is not created by using associations. Then how would it query data based on that `association`.. Also I was referring to `$this->bindModel` since I would also need to create/remove associations on the fly.

Comment: Look at the `DBOSource::read` method's code. You'll the `if` structure of relevance. If you used the same database configuration, a `LEFT JOIN` would have been used (by default) because it is a belongsTo relationship _(and if your recursive level >= 0)_.